# How To Insert USERID (Type: Raw, Size: 16) from Ora_aspnet_users to Another Table

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, odac

Sorry I cannot upload the screenshot due to the limited number of my reputation since I am a newbie here.

```
ora_aspnet_user table with column name userid with datatype of Raw(16)
link to
Instruct Table with userid with datatype of Raw (16) - Other columns is ID (Auto Trigger No), Command (Varchar2 = 256)
```

MY INLINE ASPX CODE:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            DefaultMode="Insert" Height="50px" Width="125px">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="COMMAND" HeaderText="COMMAND" SortExpression="COMMAND" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USERID">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                            DataTextField="USERNAME" DataValueField="USERID">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                   </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO INSTRUCT (COMMAND, USERID) VALUES (:COMMAND, :USERID)">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="COMMAND" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="USERID" DbType="Binary" Size="16" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT USERID, USERNAME FROM ORA_ASPNET_USERS">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code will only insert the command textbox and but will not insert the USERID from the USERID dropdown.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your datasource `<InsertParameter>` with this one, it might help you, because I don't have your source code I cannot test it locally, the problem could occur somewhere elese though:

```
<InsertParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="USERID" Type="Byte"></asp:ControlParameter>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Text" Name="COMMAND" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
</InsertParameters>
```

Comment: I replace the Insert parameter but when I click the insert button, it thrown out "Could not find control 'DropDownList1' in ControlParameter 'USERID'.". I also try to return the parameter for command <asp:Parameter Name="COMMAND" Type="String" /> since it is only a textbox but the result still the same. Could i have your email address so i can sent you the screenshot of my DB design.

Comment: I know the problem is on parameter because if i use the original parameter i posted, it can send the command but the userid will still blank in the oracle database.

Comment: To Ali Shahrokhi. Your provided above code particulary the Control Parameter helps me to further isolated the problem, now i have new concern related to the above subject. Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320916/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-and-ora-01465-invalid-hex-number .Thank you again.